# ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotation again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes, data-annotations

i.e. I have an Email field on page. I want to validate it on client (so, can't post invalid value) and server side (if client validation is disabled). There are 3 attributes, linked with Email:

1. `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`
2. `[EmailAddress]`
3. `[RegularExpression(@"...")]`

Which should we use for this purpose?

I see, that `DataTypeAttribute` is inherited from `ValidationAttribute`, but `IsValid` method is overridden and always returns true:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/DataTypeAttribute.cs,c3a0957894bdc158

But `EmailAddressAttribute` is inherited from `DataTypeAttribute` and has overridden `IsValid` also, but with logic depend on Regex.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs,c3ae85dfd8a9f58c

So, in any case, we have to use `[EmailAddress]` without `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` because `[EmailAddress]` extends `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`.

Let's look on to use `[EmailAddress]` or `[RegularExpression(@"...")]`. Seems to me, we have to use `[EmailAddress]` because it has "benefits" from `DataTypeAttribute`. So, correct way is use only `[EmailAddress]`. Am I right?

Comment: Even though `[DataType]` derives from `ValidationAttribute`, it has nothing to do with mvc's validation (its used to render the `type="email"` when using `EditorFor()`). `[EmailAddress]` is in effect a `RegularExpressionAttribute` - your can see the regex it uses in the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I say the same. But want to be sure, that `[EmailAddress]` is enough to use. No necessary to use `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` and `[RegularExpression(@"...")]`, right?

Comment: Using `[EmailAddress]` is correct (however due to a lack of coordination between MS and the developers of `jquery.validate.js`, there is a minor difference in the regex that is used, so in some cases the value will be valid on the client but invalid on the server

Comment: If you want to ensure they match, you can also override the `$.validator` method for `email` to use the regex in `[EmailAddress]`. Alternatively, create you own attribute that derives from `RegularExpressionAttribute` that uses the regex from `jquery.validate.js`